# Which design pattern should I use for notifications?

Tags: php, laravel-5, design-patterns, notifications, queue

I am working on laravel project using queues.
My 'checkAgeAndNotify' API will check if age is greater than 50, then it will send email notification to that user using queue.

```
class Age extends Controller
 {
    public function checkAgeAndNotify(Request $request)
    {
       if(Input::get('age') > 50){
           $job = (new notification());
           dispatch($job);
       }
    }
 }
```

Following is my job class:

```
class notification implements ShouldQueue
 {
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;
    public construct(){}

    public function handle()
    {
        Mail::send('welcome', $data, function ($message) use ($data) {
                $message->from('my-test@gmail.com', 'unknown-sender');
                $message->to('alpha@test.com')->subject('Test Email');
        });
    }

}
```

My code is working 100% perfectly. But I am not sure how to transform my code using any design pattern according to the situation.

If pattern could not be applied in this small code. So, we can assume that we have multiple channels to send notifications such as email, via sms and etc.

Comment: If the "_code is working 100% perfectly_" then why add any design pattern?

Comment: Well, it is my professor's requirement to implement design pattern.

Comment: You can use Command-Event Pattern or Observer Patterns.

Comment: Consider renaming your classes and using consistent case e.g. AgeNotifier and NotificationJob

Answer (score 0):

Your professor is bound to want you to be implementing the Observer pattern since the observers (the users) get notified.